# executing a command on pairedf iles and then renaming the outputs

Tags: bash, unix, fastq

`command.py`, that merges together two paired files, `CA01_S1_R1.fastq`and `CA01_S1_R2.fastq`. It then prints the result into a new directory `paired.out` and names the resulting file `paired.fastq`. The full command would read

`command.py -f CA01_S1_R1.fastq -r CA01_S1_R2.fastq -o paired.out`

However, I would like to execute this command on many files, and then have all of the outputs saved into the same directory. Furthermore, the outputs need to have unique names. So, I want to send files 2 and 3 as well, effectively running these commands also:

`command.py -f CA02_S2_R1.fastq -r CA02_S2_R2.fastq -o paired.out`

`command.py -f CA03_S3_R1.fastq -r CA03_S3_R2.fastq -o paired.out`

However, even if I had code to loop this command on all the samples, the command would keep overwriting the output of the last pairing, as all outputs are saved inside the folder `paired.out`, with the filename `paired.fastq`. Is there a simple loop I can write that will send each file pair through the command, then enter the folder and rename the file output from `paired.fastq` to `CA01_paired.fastq`, and then repeat for all my files?

I know that I can send multiple files through the command using:

```
for f in CA*_S*_R1.fastq; do
# Replace R1 with R2 in the filename and run the command on both files.
command.py -f "$f" -r "${f/R1/R2}" -o paired.ends
done; unset -v f
```

I'd like to add a second instruction to this loop to just cd into this folder, and rename the file, incrementing by 1 each time. I don't know how to set the increment variable. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
for f in CA*_S*_R1.fastq; do
# Replace R1 with R2 in the filename and run the command on both files.
command.py -f "$f" -r "${f/R1/R2}" -o paired.ends
#cd into the output folder
cd paired.ends
#create an environmental variable that keep tracks of which file number I am on
g=01
#rename the output file
mv fastqjoin.join.fastq CA$g_fastqjoin.join.fastq
#update the environmental variable that keeps track of which file number I am on
g= g + 1
#cd out of the folder where the outputs are being stored and back to the folder that contains all the files to be paired.
cd ..
done; unset -v f
```

Comment: Your pairings are unclear. You have CA01 with CA01 and CA02 with CA01 and CA03 with CA02. What is the pattern?

Comment: my fault, this was a typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files are paired via `blah_R1.fastq` and `blah_R2.fastq`:

```
for f in *_R1.fastq; do
    r=${f/_R1/_R2}
    command.py -f "$f" -r "$r" -o paired.out &&
        mv paired.out/paired.fastq paired.out/"${f%%_*}_paired.fastq"
done
```